# What brooms do the Weasleys own?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-items, magical-transportation, flying-brooms

I know the Weasleys all use older brooms, but do we know what brooms they own?

I remember that over the summer Harry and the Weasleys all play pick up games of Quidditch in the woods near the Weasleys' house and that they all take turns using Harry's broom since it's so fancy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Fred, George, and Ron use Cleansweeps.

Fred and George use **Cleansweep Fives**, at least in *HP and the Chamber of Secrets*, as we see from Malfoy's taunting them after he buys Nimbus 2001's for the entire Slytherin team:

> "You could raffle off those Cleansweep Fives, I expect a museum would bid for them."
>   <sub>-- Draco Malfoy, *HP and the Chamber of Secrets*</sub>

The brand of the twins' brooms is once more confirmed in *HP and the Order of the Phoenix*:

> Then there were the two large broom-shaped holes in Umbridge's office door, through which Fred and George's Cleansweeps had smashed to rejoin their masters.

And they've never had new brooms, so they must have been using the same Cleansweep Fives all the way through:

> "they've [Fred and George] never had new brooms! I wish I could go with Mum and choose: she'll never be able to afford a Nimbus, but there's the new Cleansweep out, that'd be great: yeah, I think I'll go and tell her I like the Cleansweep, just so she knows."
>   <sub>-- Ron Weasley, *HP and the Order of the Phoenix*</sub>

The above quote concerns Ron getting a Cleansweep as a reward for becoming a prefect. In the next book we discover that this is a **Cleansweep Eleven**:

> Ron looked ready to pass out as he mounted his Cleansweep Eleven.
>   <sub>-- *HP and the Half-Blood Prince*</sub>

According to [HP Lexicon](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/wizworld/brooms.html), this is the sum total of what we know about the Weasleys' broomsticks.

Comment: i thought ginny used something else in book 2 or 4 when they are playing quiditch at their house

Comment: @Himarm [Seemingly](http://www.cosforums.com/cosarchive/archive/index.php/t-45233.html) it's not known what broom Ginny used.

Comment: i new they included other brooms they owned!

Comment: yeah yeah you can keep your accepted :P

Answer (score 3):

Ron before getting his Cleansweep Eleven was using a [Shooting Star](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Shooting_Star).

> Ron's old Shooting Star was often outstripped by passing butterflies.